# Equality of a random variable implies equality on conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I had this basic conjecture about random variables. Let $X$, $Y$ random variables on the same measure space.

Original claim: If for elementary events $\omega_1,\omega_2$ we have $Y(\omega_1)=Y(\omega_2)$, then also $E[X|Y](\omega_1)=E[X|Y](\omega_2)$.

I think the claim as it is cannot be correct since the expectation value is a random variable, defined therefore up only to equivalence, and we can change representative changing the value on a zero measure set. Nevertheless I think intuitively there should be a related statement because what the expectation value $E[X|Y]$ is doing, to my understanding, is taking a local mean of $X$ over a set where $Y$ assumes the same value. My questions are:

- does it exist a version of this claim that makes sense from a measure-theoretic point of view ? If this version of the claim exists, this new version is also true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjecture is basically right. The conjecture, phrased differently, is that $E[X|Y]$ is a function of $Y$. A version of the conditional expectation (by definition) is measurable wrt the conditioning variable, thus a function of the conditioning variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight! So you mean that the claim is true for every couple of events $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ (without having to modify the statement), provided that one chooses a version of the conditional expectation measurable wrt to the conditioning variable?

Comment: No problem--it's a general statement, if $U$ is borel measurable wrt $V$, then $V(\omega_1)\neq V(\omega_2)\Rightarrow U(\omega_1)\neq U(\omega_2)$. Inuitively, $V(\omega_1)=V(\omega_2)$ means any set in $\sigma(V)$ that contains $\omega_1$ also contains $\omega_2$. By the same, $U(\omega_1)\neq U(\omega_2)$ implies sets in $\sigma(U)$ that separate $\omega_1,\omega_2$, contradicting $\sigma(U)\subset \sigma(V)$.